# OpenCV MergeMertens gives different results in Python Vs. C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv, hdr

When I run the HDR Mertens exposure fusion in Python I get weird colors artifact, that I don't get when I run the exact same function in c++. (I just run the [HDR Tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/db7/tutorial_hdr_imaging.html#gsc.tab=0))

Seems to me like some problem with the data types, but I tried every option and nothing works. Am I doing something wrong?

I'm running Python 3.5 64-bit with OpenCV 3.0.0.

**The exposures images were taken from Wikipedia:** [1/30 sec](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/09/StLouisArchMultExpEV-4.72.JPG/640px-StLouisArchMultExpEV-4.72.JPG), [1/4 sec](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c3/StLouisArchMultExpEV-1.82.JPG/640px-StLouisArchMultExpEV-1.82.JPG),  [2.5 sec](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/89/StLouisArchMultExpEV%2B1.51.JPG/640px-StLouisArchMultExpEV%2B1.51.JPG),  [15 sec](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8f/StLouisArchMultExpEV%2B4.09.JPG/640px-StLouisArchMultExpEV%2B4.09.JPG).

**The Python code:**

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_fn = ["640px-StLouisArchMultExpEV+4.09.jpg",
          "640px-StLouisArchMultExpEV+1.51.jpg",
          "640px-StLouisArchMultExpEV-1.82.jpg",
          "640px-StLouisArchMultExpEV-4.72.jpg"]
img_list = [cv2.imread(fn) for fn in img_fn]

# Exposure fusion using Mertens
mergeMertens = cv2.createMergeMertens()
resFusion = mergeMertens.process(img_list)

# Convert datatype to 8-bit and save
resFusion_8bit = np.uint8(resFusion*255)
cv2.imwrite("fusion.png", resFusion_8bit)
```

**The result I get in Python:**

[image]

**The result I get in C++:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens here is caused by 8 bit overflow and underflow for some of the R, G, B subpixels. Some of them are outside of the interval `[0.0 .. 1.0]`  after the fusion, and when multiplied with 255, the result will be negative or above 255.

`np.uint8` will truncate the results, and keep only the least significant 8 bits, so for example:

- a value of `-2` will be stored as `254`
- a value of `257` will be stored as `1`

This can be solved by clipping the results in the range `[0 .. 255]`, replacing

```
resFusion_8bit = np.uint8(resFusion*255)
```

with

```
np.clip(resFusion*255, 0, 255, out=resFusion)
resFusion_8bit = resFusion.astype('uint8')
```

Or, it is possible to pass directly the values multiplied with 255 to `imwrite`, without converting them first to `uint8` and it will take care of the clipping. It would be the same as it is done in the provided C++ example. So, the script can be rewritten as:

```
import cv2

img_fn = ["640px-StLouisArchMultExpEV+4.09.JPG",
          "640px-StLouisArchMultExpEV+1.51.JPG",
          "640px-StLouisArchMultExpEV-1.82.JPG",
          "640px-StLouisArchMultExpEV-4.72.JPG"]
img_list = [cv2.imread(fn) for fn in img_fn]

# Exposure fusion using Mertens
mergeMertens = cv2.createMergeMertens()
resFusion = mergeMertens.process(img_list)

# Save
cv2.imwrite("fusion.png", resFusion*255)
```

(Note that I replaced the file extensions with `.JPG` - uppercase, as this is the original name on Wikipedia and I've ran this on Linux, where filenames are case sensitive.)